# Why is the Azure B2C Access Token so long

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

The access token I get back from Azure B2C is 926 characters for local email login and 1354 characters for facebook login. The facebook login is longer because I include the user picture in the token, but other than that I do not put any user data in the token (not name, username or anything else like that).

Since I have to send the access token to every call to the API to get data I was wondering why it is so long and what might affect it. Have I configured something that increases its length or is this just normal?

A censored version of the decoded jwt from jwt.ms:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "***"
}.{
  "exp": ***,
  "nbf": ***,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "***",
  "sub": "***",
  "aud": "***",
  "acr": "b2c_1a_signup_signin",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "iat": ***,
  "auth_time": ***,
  "picture": "***",
  "idp": "facebook.com",
  "tid": "***"
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: The only thing that affects token length is what is in the header and payload (and I guess the signature algorithm). Is there something in the payload that you would want to remove from there?

Comment: It's long because of the form it has in AAD B2C - JWT. It's not an opaque token like you can sometimes see in other solutions. The con is the size, the pro is that the recipient can validate it without calling the issuer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT has 3 sections, header, payload, signature. You can only influence the length of the payload, which is configured by what claims you want Azure AD B2C to put into the token.

Your whole payload is made mostly of required claims, other than idp and picture claims.

There is nothing to optimise here if those two claims are required.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is not a problem, I just wanted to make sure I was not doing something wrong. Interestingly I see the header is actually smaller for facebook, 68 characters as opposed to 107 for email. 

I reduced the payload by removing picture, identityProvider and tenantId as I do not use these. That gets the payload down to 416 and the total size to 865 characters.

The signature is always 343.

Comment: PS! I removed picture and then I get it from the Graph API instead in the backend. I need to get the picture from the backend API anyway since users can override their facebook picture with an account picture.